# Push on other ViewController from ChatViewController created with MessageKit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, pushviewcontroller, messagekit

I use `MessageKit` for create `Chat` in my `App`.

In `ChatViewController` which i created programmatically I added `rightBarButtonItem` with `user picture`. I want to add **func** which will be redirect on `UserProfileViewController` if other user hits on `rightBarButtonItem`.

Now it looks like this. User picture dedicated blue color with arrows.

[image]

Now I have this code:

```
class ChatsViewController: MessagesViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        maintainPositionOnKeyboardFrameChanged = true
        messageInputBar.sendButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "send"), for: .normal)
        messageInputBar.sendButton.title = nil

        messageInputBar.inputTextView.placeholder = NSLocalizedString("New message", comment: "Новое сообщение")

        messageInputBar.delegate = self
        messagesCollectionView.messagesDataSource = self
        messagesCollectionView.messagesLayoutDelegate = self
        messagesCollectionView.messagesDisplayDelegate = self
        messagesCollectionView.messageCellDelegate = self
    }

    private func loadChat(channel: Channel) {
        guard let id = channel.id else {
            navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
            return
        }

        reference = db.collection([FSCollections.chats, id, "thread"].joined(separator: "/"))

        messageListener = reference?.addSnapshotListener { querySnapshot, error in
            guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
                print("Error listening for channel updates: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No error")")
                return
            }

            if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.switcherIsClick) == true {
                self.navigationItem.title = self.channel?.recipientName ?? ""
            } else {
                self.navigationItem.title = self.channel?.name ?? ""
            }
            self.configurePhotoProfile()

            snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { change in
                self.handleDocumentChange(change)
            }
        }
    }

    func configurePhotoProfile() {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        let widthConstraint = imageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 34)
        let heightConstraint = imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 34)
        let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ChatsViewController.didTapImageButton(_:)))
        tap.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1
        heightConstraint.isActive = true
        widthConstraint.isActive = true
        imageView.kf.setImage(with: URL(string: channel?.recipientUrlImage ?? ""))
        imageView.backgroundColor = .clear
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 17
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
        if UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: UserDefaultsKeys.selectedSegmentedControl) == 0 {
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: imageView)
        } else {
            self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = nil
        }
    }

    @objc func didTapImageButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {

        if let detailPhotographerVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "detailPhotographerVC") as? DetailPhotographerViewController {
            detailPhotographerVC.id = channel?.recipientID ?? ""
            let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
            backItem.title = ""
            self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailPhotographerVC, animated: true)
        } else {
            print("error")
        }
    }
}
```

So, if user tap on `user picture` I get an error in **console** from `func didTapImageButton`.

I don't understand why I get an error... On `detailPhotographerVC` I redirect correct `id` and `detailPhotographerVC` must not accept any data other than id.

**UPD.**

I try update my code in `func didTapImageButton` on:

```
@objc func didTapImageButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let detailPhotographerVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "detailPhotographerVC") as! DetailPhotographerViewController
    detailPhotographerVC.id = channel?.recipientID ?? ""
    let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
    backItem.title = ""
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(detailPhotographerVC, animated: true)
}
```

But again get an error, check screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I get `print("error")` in func `didTapImageButton` without redirect on `detailPhotographerVC`

Comment: remove `if` and try below line , tell what crash if you get 1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load vc programmatically

```
let detailPhotographerVC =  DetailPhotographerViewController()
```

from storyboard

```
let detailPhotographerVC = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "detailPhotographerVC") as! DetailPhotographerViewController
```

Comment: didn't help me, pls check upd question

Comment: Do you have a storyboard named "Main" ?

Comment: Oh, no, but I tried to add it and it help me, big thanks!:)